# ausmachen to express to disturb / be disturbed

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, grammatical-case

Would you deem the construct with `ausmachen` semantically and grammatically correct:

```
Könnten Sie darauf achten, dass ihm keiner etwas ausmacht?
```

Maybe we can say

```
Könnten Sie darauf achten, dass ihm niemand etwas ausmacht?
```

or

```
Könnten Sie darauf achten, dass er nichts ausgemacht wird?
```

What will be competing expressions?

Comment: None of your sentences is correct with the word "*ausmacht*" related to being disturbed / he doesn't mind. In the first two I would understand "*ausmacht*" as "*switch off*"/"*turn off*", but the sentences with "etwas" are a bit strange. ("*niemand*" and "*keiner*" are synonyms.) The second half of the third sentence doesn't make any sense at all. Can you write in English what you are trying to say?

Comment: Kommst Du über die Phrase "das macht mir nichts aus"/"das macht wir etwas aus" zu Deiner Übersetzung? Wenn man ein komplexes Laborsetting über das Wochenende unbeaufsichtigt laufen lässt, könnte man auch eine der ersten Beiden Formulierungen wählen, aber mein Eindruck ist nicht, dass das hier gefragt ist (eine Maschine ausmachen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two sentences are syntactically correct, but semantically wrong because *ausmachen* is not used in this way.

*Ausmachen* can have the meaning of "to bother" but it is generally used with actions and things, not with persons. It does not express the objective action of bothering someone but rather causing the subjective feeling of being bothered. An example for correct usage would be:

> Macht es Ihnen etwas aus, wenn ich das Fenster schließe?

When it's about persons, *stören* should be used instead. *Stören* also has the benefit of being easier to use, taking only one object instead of two.

The third sentence is syntactically wrong because *er* is incorrect here. See the question [Can you say “Ich wurde (etwas) gegeben”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/64706/can-you-say-ich-wurde-etwas-gegeben)

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks context, one can only guess what you want to express. As RHa explained, only the first two sentences are syntactically correct. You *could* understand them as Bodo and user unknown have suggested in their comments, in the sense that "etwas ausmacht" means "etwas abschaltet" (switch off something which is important for the person).

Most likely you want to say

> Could you take care that nobody disturbs him.

This would be

> Könnten Sie darauf achten, dass ihn keiner stört.

I guess you used the verb "ausmachen" because one correctly says

> Es macht ihm nicht aus / Es macht ihm etwas aus

which comes very close to

> Es stört ihn nicht / Es stört ihn